# Unity Opencv difference image / convert type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, opencv, type-conversion

I try to make an application in unity, using OpenCV. I need the `Absdiff` from two pictures.

My Problem is that I get an `OpenCvSharp.OutputArray` from the `Cv2.Absdiff(processImageTwo, processImageOne, differenceImage);` function and I cant't convert it to a `byte[]`, which I'll need to store the image.
Can somebody help me, how to convert an `OpenCvSharp.OutputArray` to byte?

Comment: To which byte format do you want to convert the output? Did you try `differenceImage.toBytes()`?

Comment: thanks for your answer. 
i need the local byte type to save it with (WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
i can't find that funtion toBytes at the OutputArray

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
byte[] bytes = differenceImage.GetMat().ToBytes();
```

This should convert the image to png byte format.

See https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs

Comment: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74293585/solution-toopencv-error-convert-image-to-gray?noredirect=1#comment131162996_74293585)