# "OpenCVException: scn == 3 || scn == 4" when I convert image to gray

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, opencv

When I try to load the image and convert it to gray, I get this error:

> OpenCVException: scn == 3 || scn == 4

It occours when i try to convert the `image1` to gray and save it in `proccessImageOne` at the line:

```
Cv2.CvtColor(image1, processImageOne, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
```

I have already checked if the image is empty and if it really exists in the folder.

Here is my code:

```
imageName = "/images/test/img4.png";
var image = File.ReadAllBytes(Application.dataPath + imageName);
Debug.Log("Type = " + image.GetValue(0));
if (image == null) 
  { Debug.Log("could not load image !"); 
  } 
Texture2D tex = new(Screen.width, Screen.height);
tex.LoadImage(image);
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
var image1 = OpenCvSharp.InputArray.Create(image);
Cv2.CvtColor(image1, processImageOne, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
```

Can someone help me to find the failure, please :)

Comment: Ok, so that message is an `Exception` right?  So can you put a try-catch around this and 
 dump the text of the `Exception` (its `Message` property) out somewhere?  Or even better examine it interactively in the debugger?

Comment: I see several CS files and line numbers in your call stack, but I don't actually see the error. You haven't told us which file you're using to create this snippet, and you haven't told us which line is the one that's causing the error, and you haven't told us what the error is. This makes it really difficult for us to help you.

Comment: thanks for answering.
so the Error Name is: OpenCVException: scn == 3 || scn == 4
it occours at the line : `Cv2.CvtColor(image1, processImageOne, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);`  when i try to convert the image1 to gray and save it in proccessImagOne. I try to load an image, which i saved bevor as `var bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The byte data in `image` is still png-encoded. Try to create a `Mat` from the encoded image data like this:

```
Mat image1 = OpenCvSharp.Mat.FromImageData(image);
Cv2.CvtColor(image1, processImageOne, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
```

See https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs